# How is it possible to MOVE.W a 24-Bit value?

Tags: assembly, 68000

I am in the process of learning assembly and using a tutorial to guide me through the learning process.  In this case, I am learning the Motorola 68000 to do some programming on the Sega Genesis compiling with VASM.

Take the following snippet:

```
VDP_ctrl EQU $C00004   ;VDP control, word or longword writes only
MOVE.W (VDP_ctrl),D5   ;$C00004 read VDP status (interupt acknowledge)?
```

Understanding that `MOVE.W` is meant for a 16-bit WORD value into a register (`D5` in this case), and `$C00004` is a 24-bit hex value, how is this possible?  This does compile and works on the Sega emulator Fusion.

For full context, the tutorial is located at https://www.chibiakumas.com/68000/helloworld.php#LessonH1

Book to follow along: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08W7DWZB3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08W7DWZB3)

Comment: The parenthesis around the symbolic address is not needed (some assemblers, including Motorola's would even choke at it). m68k assembly is designed in a way that `move` always implies indirect addresses (as opposed to `lea`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no 24-bit data being manipulated here. What is 24-bit is the address. The instruction

```
MOVE.W (VDP_ctrl),D5
```

is moving data between the word at the *address* `VDP_ctrl` and the register `D5`.

Note the parentheses. In assembly, these are often used to indicate a level of indirection. Similarly, `(A0)` indicates that data is being accessed at the address held in `A0`, as opposed to the contents of `A0` itself:

```
MOVEA.L D0, A0      ; Copies the contents of D0 into A0 (most assemblers accept MOVE.L)
MOVE.L  D0, (A0)    ; Copies the contents of D0 into the longword at address A0
```

Comment: This instruction will encode a full 32-bit absolute address (of which probably only 24 bits are relevant).

Comment: Oh wait, the `()` indicates the indirect addressing, and the address points to the 16-bit value `VDP_ctrl` points at?

Comment: @ChadHarrison, yes, the address is 32 bits (encoded) and the data transfer size (memory read) is 16 bits.

Comment: Just for info, the ```()``` technically aren't what makes it indirection - it's really the lack of a ```#``` in front of ```vdp_ctrl```. That being said, ```()``` do indicate indirection on address registers, so for consistency it can be handy to use ```()``` to enclose constant memory addresses if you find it easier for you.